# Get PDO connection ID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there a way to get a unique connection id of a PDO connection to mysql?

Comment: What do you want to do with this id? E.g.: Compare objects? Find correlating entries in mysql general query log? Implements some kind of connection pooling? ...?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try sth like this.

```
print_r($dbh->query('SELECT CONNECTION_ID()')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

you can use a regular query to execute the CONNECTION_ID() mysql command to get the connection ID.

[See the mySQL manual for more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id)